# How can I return a value inside Select() Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda

See the following example, now I need to check if `UserService.GetByUserID()` is null then return `String.Empty`. How can I still do this in one line?

```
var benefits = customerBenefits.Select(n =>
    new CustomerBenefit(n.BenefitID,
        n.AddedByUserID.HasValue 
            ? UserService.GetByUserID(n.AddedByUserID.Value).DisplayName 
            : n.AddedByAgentID, n.Reason);
```

Comment: *Where* do you want to return an empty string? It would be very odd to return either an empty string or a `CustomerBenefit`. Do you mean you need it for one of the constructor arguments? It would really help if you'd give more information.

Comment: I need to add another condition to check if the GetByUserID() return null then return emptystring else return DisplayName

Comment: And do you really want to use `AddedByAgentId` instead of a display name if there isn't an `AddedByUserId`? Don't you want to look up the agent's display name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Call service first then assign result.

var benefits = customerBenefits
                        .Select(n => {
                            var user = serService.GetByUserID(n.AddedByUserID.Value);

                            return new CustomerBenefit(
                                n.BenefitID,                   
                                n.AddedByUserID.HasValue ? (user== null ? String.Empty : ).DisplayName) : n.AddedByAgentID,
                                n.Reason} );
```

Answer (score 2):

By using let in query syntax, you can store sub results:

```
var benefits = from n in customerBenefits
    let hasuserid = n.AddedByUserID.HasValue
    let user = hasuserid ? UserService.GetByUserID(n.AddedByUserID.Value) : null //the call to GetUserID is stored here
           select
                new CustomerBenefit(
                    n.BenefitID,                   
                    hasuserid 
                         ? (user == null ? string.Empty : user.DisplayName) //the stored sub result is reused
                         : n.AddedByAgentID,
                    n.Reason);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
var benefits = customerBenefits.Select(n =>
        new CustomerBenefit(
            n.BenefitID,                   
            n.AddedByUserID.HasValue 
                ? (UserService.GetByUserID(n.AddedByUserID.Value) == null 
                    ? String.Empty 
                    : UserService.GetByUserID(n.AddedByUserID.Value).
                        DisplayName) 
            : n.AddedByAgentID,
            n.Reason);
```

Comment: I know but GetByUserID() gets called twice.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
var benefits = from n in customerBenefits
    let id = n.AddedByUserID.HasValue
    let user = id ? UserService.GetByUserID(n.AddedByUserID.Value) : null            select
                new CustomerBenefit(
                    n.BenefitID,                   
                    id ? (user == null ? string.Empty : user.DisplayName)
                         : n.AddedByAgentID,
                    n.Reason);
```

Comment: It is what I want to do but I don't want GetByUserID() to be called twice.